# Replacing URL ID by title on Laravel ** Without using model ** [Slug]

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I want to pass a link with ID and show the title of this id in URL [SEO] without using any Model

```
<a href="/salons/{{ $salon->id()}}" >Book Appointment</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean "without using any model"? So where does this title come from?

Comment: from Firebase[Cloud firestore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing, 
Pass id from here and in controller get data from id, title but when page render you can 
use javascript replace state.

You can replace your id with title once page render.

It will just replace your url. 
And also you have to put there condition that if title is integer when click on link (In which you passed id) you have to fetch data based on id for that you can use `laravel when` method for conditional data fetch. And if slug passed (When page rendered and title is replaced with id) you have to fetch it based on title-slug.

[Javascript Replace State(URL)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState#:~:text=The%20state%20object%20is%20a,state%20object%20can%20be%20null%20.&text=Most%20browsers%20currently%20ignores%20this,future%20changes%20to%20the%20method)

[Laravel Conditional Query](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: but there are a problem when I'm refreshing  page it must be redirect to UserID not to title as it was , can you help ?

Comment: That's why I have specified that replace will be works just as a new URL if you want to work on refresh page either you have to replace id with title by appending after replacement of id which you have to pass from controller and have to put condition in controller for string or keep I'd as it is. Ultimately replace your id with title and put condition in controller for if passed Param is id then find based on id or if string passed then find based on slug.

Comment: And you don't need to replace your full URL just replace your last part which is may be id. Customize your URL based on you requirement. :)